# Can't find object member in ijson

Tags: python, json, ijson

[json tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbSJM.png)

Full json; https://api.trendyol.com/webbrowsinggw/api/review/31515569
I need "totalPages" element under the product reviews but i can't.There is no error messages just freezing. I can access the result > productReviews > content > 0 > comment . Or others. Same code does not work to access totalPages. Here is my code the access comments;

```
import requests
import ijson

jsonAdress="https://api.trendyol.com/webbrowsinggw/api/review/31515569"
requests_session = requests.Session()
r = requests_session.get(jsonAdress)
objects = ijson.items(r.content, 'result.productReviews.content.item')

for obj in objects:
    print(obj["comment"])
```

I'm using this code to access totalPages;

```
r = requests_session.get(jsonAdress)
objects = ijson.items(r.content, 'result.item')
for obj in objects:
    print(obj["totalPages"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to a wrong item in your response.
Correct code is:

```
r = requests_session.get(jsonAdress).json()

total_pages = r.get('result').get('productReviews').get('totalPages')
print(total_pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
for obj in objects:
    print(obj["result"]["ProductReviews"]["totalPages"])
```